# how to make install-able web server

Tags: networking, server, system-installation

I wonder to make dvd that when install ubuntu automatically install the files that need to make web server work and the website inside it work too.

this some picture to describe more :

[image]

this installation , like you install normal Ubuntu , but after installation we can access the website form the network :

[image]

please help me , and thanks for all try.

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions here for creating a custom install CD: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization

You could use that to create an install CD that automatically installs Apache on install and the component of your web site.

But it is probably easier to install a generic Ubuntu and then use a configuration management system (such as Ansible https://www.ansible.com/) to install the web server software and web site.